# Does LINQ AsParallel() preserve thread safety?

Tags: c#, linq, plinq

I'm having some doublts about concurrency using `LINQ` `AsParallel()`.

Suppose I have the following code:

```
int counter = 0;
someList.AsParallel().ForEach(item => {
    doStuff();
    counter++;
});
```

I haven't found much online...

Is it safe to do something like this? Is there a better way of doing this?

Should I do some locking action for `counter`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is it possible to preserve thread safety for generic code? The only way would be to make each thread "exclusive", so if one thread runs the other wait.. But then it wouldn't be anymore parallel! :-)

Comment: Yeah you're right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it safe to do something like this? (`counter++`)

No.

There is no thread-safety to begin with, just code that is single-threaded.

When going parallel, *you* should make sure everything is thread-safe.
In this case:

```
//counter++;
Interlocked.Increment(ref counter);
```

And we can't see what `DoStuff()` is doing. All invocations should be independent (or use a form of locking).